# Batch change PDF font size

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have a large number (over 1000) PDF files that have been generated from HTML. The font size has been generated incorrectly. I need to change the font size whilst preserving the layout, but the main paragraphs of the PDF are not of fixed length (there's user input in the main part), so there's no easy way to extract the data and rerun it through the original generator.

Is there any way of changing the font size in-situ? If not, how could I go about extracting the paragraphs reliably, without constant line breaks in the incorrect places?